# Any examples of Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo in other languages?

Tags: syntax, language-games

I would like to know if there exist any examples of homonyms and homophones being used to create complicated linguistic constructs through lexical ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

[Lion-eating poet in the stone den](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion-Eating_Poet_in_the_Stone_Den) is a classic from Chinese linguistics. Every syllable, when read in Standard Mandarin, is pronounced as [ʂɻ̩] with one of the four tones.

Answer (score 0):

German example:

Wenn nach Fliegen Fliegen fliegen, fliegen Fliegen Fliegen nach.

Comment: also: Wenn Griechen hinter Griechen kriechen, kriechen Griechen Griechen hinterher ;)